Run a command, immediately return to the shell prompt, do not return a message when the command is finished
brew install gh > /dev/null 2>&1 &

This returns to the shell immediately, but prints [1]  + done       brew install gh > /dev/null 2>&1 when the command finishes.
brew install gh &> /dev/null

This prints nothing when the command returns, but does not return you to the shell until the command finishes.
brew install gh &> /dev/null &

This has the same effect as the first one.
How do I send the command to a background process where it will continue to run, allowing me to immediately return to the shell prompt, and where it will not return any information to my current shell environment when it finishes? It is fine if it logs the output of the command somewhere else, just not in the shell environment I'm working in.

Does this answer your question? Preventing bash from displaying "Done" when a background command finishes executing . It's for Bash, but the solutions should work in Zsh as well.
